# Shiny R - Creating a new data.frame for a model

Tags: r, shiny

I am quite new to R and even newer to Shiny.
I have an R script which I now want to convert to Shiny but I always fail.

I have a dataset with the variables Wanddicke, T1, T2, T2star, ADC, Vivo, which is saved in "Basisdaten.csv". In addition there is a variable DSS which defines the outcome (either 0 or 1).
I want this file to be loaded and a GLM Model should be trained with this dataset to predict "DSS".
Then I want to give the user a chance to enter own parameters for Wanddicke, T1, T2, T2star, ADC, Vivo, and I want the prediction to be returned by Shiny.

This is what I have up to now, but for reasons I do not unterstand it will not run. Can someone tell me where my mistakes are? I suspect the problem occurs during generation of the new data.frame "mydatanew". Thanks a lot in advance.

**UI.R**

```
 library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Colitis Evaluator"),

  # Sidebar  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       numericInput("Dicke",
                   "Wanddicke in mm:",
                   ""),
       numericInput("T1",
                    "T1 in ms:",
                    ""),
       numericInput("T2",
                    "T2 in ms:",
                    ""),
       numericInput("T2star",
                    "T2* in ms:",
                    ""),
       numericInput("ADC",
                    "ADC in 10^-6 mm^2/s",
                    ""),
       numericInput("Vivo",
                    "In Vivo als 1",
                    ""),

       #  selectInput("Vivo", "In vivo/Ex vivo:", 
       #               choices = c("In vivo" = 1, "Ex vivo" = 0))

    submitButton("Submit")

    ),


    mainPanel(

      textOutput("Score")


    )
  )
))
```

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)

Basisdaten <- read.table("Basisdaten.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
model.glm <- glm(formula=DSS==1 ~ Wanddicke + T1 + T2 + T2star + ADC + Vivo + (Wanddicke+T1+T2+T2star+ADC+Vivo)^3,family=binomial(),data=Basisdaten,na.action=na.omit)



shinyServer(function(input, output) {



     mydatanew <- data.frame(Wanddicke=input$Dicke,T1=input$T1,T2=input$T2,T2star=input$T2star,ADC=input$ADC,Vivo=input$Vivo)
     mydatanew$Score <- predict(model.glm, newdata=mydatanew, type="response")
     output$Score <- renderText(mydatanew$Score)


})
```

Comment: For a `numericInput`, the default value should be a number instead of an empty string.

Comment: In what way does it not run? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work.
I' ve added some sampling due to the very poor csv file ...

you may have seen in your console some complains about operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
You may find this interesting: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html

csv

```
Wanddicke,T1,T2,T2star,ADC,Vivo,DSS
10,2,3,4,5,6,0
20,4,6,8,10,12,1
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

Basisdaten <- read.table("Basisdaten.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
model.glm <- glm(formula=DSS==1 ~ Wanddicke + T1 + T2 + T2star + ADC + Vivo + (Wanddicke+T1+T2+T2star+ADC+Vivo)^3,family=binomial(),data=Basisdaten,na.action=na.omit)



shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$Score <- renderText({

    mydatanew <- data.frame(Wanddicke=input$Dicke,T1=input$T1,T2=input$T2,T2star=input$T2star,ADC=input$ADC,Vivo=input$Vivo)
    mydatanew$Score <- predict(model.glm, newdata=mydatanew, type="response")
    mydatanew$Score + sample(1:100, 1)
    })
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Colitis Evaluator"),

  # Sidebar  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("Dicke",
                   "Wanddicke in mm:",
                   10),
      numericInput("T1",
                   "T1 in ms:",
                   1),
      numericInput("T2",
                   "T2 in ms:",
                   2),
      numericInput("T2star",
                   "T2* in ms:",
                   3),
      numericInput("ADC",
                   "ADC in 10^-6 mm^2/s",
                   4),
      numericInput("Vivo",
                   "In Vivo als 1",
                   0),

      #  selectInput("Vivo", "In vivo/Ex vivo:", 
      #               choices = c("In vivo" = 1, "Ex vivo" = 0))

      submitButton("Submit")

    ),


    mainPanel(

      textOutput("Score")


    )
  )
))
```

Comment: Dear all,
thanks a lot for your immediate answers and kind comments. Unfortunately, even with tokiloutok's modifications it won't work. I just see the User interface popping up for less than one second when clicking on "Run", but before I can do anything it closes again. No error messages.

Comment: is your csv file in the same folder as you shiny files? Are you able to execute your code in plain R (oustide shiny) ?  do you see any error in the console ?

Comment: I got it...it was due to the line 
Basisdaten <- read.table("Basisdaten.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
The separator is ";" not ","
Thanks so much for your help and efforts!!